# Creating another version of existing Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, versioning

I have a Rails application named Student. Now I want to create some change to some of its existing controllers without changing the existing ones by using versioning. By searching I found versionist gem of Ruby. I have read its documentation. But I did not understand it clearly. I want to create just another version v2 of my application. My existing application has no version name. Can anyone please guide me exactly what should I do to create another version of my Rails application?

Comment: Do you want both versions to have "a life of their own" or are you just looking to apply version control to the existing project? If you're looking at version control, I'd go with a standard tool such as `git` or `svn` or `hg`. These tools are also useful for web-based code share sites like "github".

Comment: No I am not looking at version control, rather I want both versions to have life of their own so that I can access them both by urls.

Comment: Then you could just "deep copy" a project into another project folder. *E.g.*, `cp -a proj1 proj2` (if you're on Linux).

Comment: The approach you are suggesting will not work while I want to access different version of them with browser. That is why I want to use that gem so that the change is done accordingly in routes.rb to access different versions of them.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a `UsersController` and you want to create a new version v2.

1. In your `app/controllers` folder, create a `v2` folder and copy the `users_controller.rb` under it. Now, open `app/controllers/v2/users_controller.rb` and add namespace to it

   ```
   class V2::TranslationResponsesController
   ```
2. Add the new controller to your `routes.rb` in the following way

   ```
   namespace :v2 do
       resources :users
   end
   ```
3. Now, you can access the controller by added v2 to the path as `http://localhost:3000/v2/users`, while your old controller is still available at `http://localhost:3000/users`

Hope that helps

Comment: So you mean only the controllers for which I want to create a new version the above action is required and leave other controllers intact. If I am wrong, please rectify.